# Liberty profile POJO caching

Tags: java, caching, websphere-liberty

I am attempting to set up liberty profile server so I can cache POJOs. My question is how do I access the DistributedMap within my java code?

My server.xml:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>webCache-1.0</feature>
    <feature>distributedMap-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<distributedMap id="baseCache" libraryRef="TSPlib" memorySizeInMB="500" jndiName="services/cache/baseCache">
    <diskCache></diskCache>
</distributedMap>

<library id="TSPlib">
    <folder dir="C:\TSP\bin"></folder>
</library>
```

I tried this code below (which admittedly is for WAS), but I can't find the correct namespace for DistributedMap, nor the jar that it's in.

public class CachingService {

```
private DistributedMap cache = null;

public CachingService() {
    InitialContext ctx;
    try {
    ctx = new InitialContext();
          cache = (DistributedMap) ctx.lookup("services/cache/baseCache");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo, as in distributedMap configuration you provided `jndiName="services/cache/baseCache"` and in lookup you use: `ctx.lookup("services/cache/TestCache")`

If you would not provide custom jndiName, then the default `services/cache/distributedmap`. See [distributedMap-1.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html%23rwlp_feat__distributedMap-1.0?lang=en-us)

Comment: Yep, that's certainly a problem too, but the main problem is I can't even get the code to compile. I'm not sure what the namespace for DistributedMap is. Autocomplete within eclipse doesn't bring up any classes for me, and a search on google hasn't found the jar either.

Comment: (I've edited the question to take into consideration this error.)

Comment: @JamesHutchinson How are you building this? If you would use Eclipse with WebSphere Liberty as target runtime, it should already be in the class path. The jar is in the `wlp\dev\api\ibm\com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.distributedMap-*.jar`.

Comment: @JamesHutchinson Ahh, by namespace you mean package name? It is  `com.ibm.websphere.cache.DistributedMap`